# cancel button not working

Tags: javascript, jsp

my cancel button redirects to another page.

```
onClick='window.location="../nsmapi-ui/ListMessageSetup.jsp"'
```

in safari when click this button it also save values into database.
my save button has another onclick event which doesnot fire on cancel button.

Comment: Try change to window.location.href....

Comment: Question is hard to understand @farjad. What do you mean by save button having an onclick event which doesn't fire on cancel button.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should remove the `type="submit"` from the button.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your question, and I believe you are saying that you have two onClick events, one that is shared by both the save and the cancel buttons, and one that is unique to the cancel button, which you posted above.

I think the problem is that when you redirect someone, the second onClick even does not fire becaues they have already left your page and being redirected to another page already.